# JDE 4.6.0 BlackBerry

Tags: api, blackberry, version, blackberry-jde

I'm searching on internet a old version of blackberry JDE (4.6.0), have you got a link to download this ?

Answer (score 3):

if you are using blackberry eclipse java plugin you can install software at

```
http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/java
```

Comment: 404 not found ... And yes i use eclipse java plugin.

Comment: on eclipse. open help menu button click install new software. there is a text field labelled "Work with:". You are gonna type this link there. Click next. there should be several SDKs over there. Pick one and install it.

Answer (score 2):

hope this will work

http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javadevenv.jsp